# (Read and) Parse an XML file from Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a large number of *.xml files in Internal Storage. I did not create these files myself, but I need to work with them. They are structured like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ControlFrame xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <LandCode>31</LandCode>
     <LandName>Australia</LandName>
     <strFormat>Format35to45</strFormat>
     <bUseOverlay>true</bUseOverlay>
     ...
</ControlFrame>
```

The user selects one of the `*.xml` files from a list, and I generate a `File` object for the correct `*.xml`

Next, I need to query the `*.xml` file for properties like `LandCode` or `bUseOverlay`.

I have tried everything, but I can not get it to work on Jellybean 4.3.

What is my best approach and how do I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need is [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

> XPath, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes
>   from an XML document.

There is a [`javax.xml.xpath`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) that allows you to make XPath expressions and retrieve nodes.

Aside:
[Pimp my XSLT](http://pimpmyxslt.com/axesviz.aspx) is a great resource if you are planning on learning XPath.